# pyspark using one task for mapPartitions when converting rdd to dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm confused as to why it appears that Spark is using 1 task for `rdd.mapPartitions` when converting the resulting RDD to a DataFrame.

This is an issue for me because I would like to go from :

`DataFrame` --> `RDD` --> `rdd.mapPartitions` --> `DataFrame`

so that I can read in data (DataFrame), apply a non-SQL function to chunks of data (mapPartitions on RDD) and then convert back to a DataFrame so that I can using the `DataFrame.write` process.

I am able to go from DataFrame --> mapPartitions and then use an RDD writer like saveAsTextFile but that is less than ideal since the `DataFrame.write` process can do things like overwrite and save data in Orc format. So I'd like to learn *why* this is going on, but from a pratical perspective I'm primarily concerned with being able to just go from a DataFrame --> mapParitions --> to using the DataFrame.write process.

Here is a reproducible example. The following works as expected, with 100 tasks for the `mapPartitions` work:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("yarn-client") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':range(100000),'var2': [x-1000 for x in range(100000)]})
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df).repartition(100)

def f(part):
    return [(1,2)]

spark_df.rdd.mapPartitions(f).collect()
```

However if the last line is change to something like `spark_df.rdd.mapPartitions(f).toDF().show()` then there will only be one task for the `mapPartitions` work.

Some screenshots illustrating this below:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataFrame.show()` only shows the first number of rows of your dataframe, by default only the first 20. If that number is smaller than the number of rows per partition, Spark is lazy and only evaluates a single partition, which is equivalent to a single task.

You can also do `collect` on a dataframe, to compute and collect all partitions and see 100 tasks again.

You will still see the `runJob` task first as before, which is caused by the `toDF` call to be able to determine the resulting dataframe's schema: it needs to process a single partition to be able to determine the output types of your mapping function. After this initial stage the actual action such as `collect` will happen on all partitons. For instance, for me running your snippet with the last line replaced with `spark_df.rdd.mapPartitions(f).toDF().collect()` results in these stages:

[image]

Comment: The same happens when calling `DataFrame.write` on the result as well.

Comment: Are you waiting for your jobs to finish completely? When I do `toDF().collect()`, I see a `runJob` stage with one task too, initiated by the `toDF` to check the schema of the resulting dataframe, followed by a `collect` stage with the expected 100 tasks.

Comment: `collect()` isn't a feasible thing for me to do in real-life given that the end result is a few hundred GB of data. Jobs fail when running `DataFrame.write` with only 1 task but succeed when running `saveAsText`. I'll edit the examples from collect & show to saving data since there may be difference between those.

Comment: Ugh, maybe you're right. I need to figure out why this is failing on real data at the 1 task step.

Comment: I used `collect` just as an example, another action such as `write` does the same, e.g. with `toDF().write.csv('/tmp/test.csv')` I get a `csv` 3rd stage with again 100 tasks. It indeed seems like you have some other issue, good luck!